# Bug app con Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo un bug en mi aplicacion.
Hice un if que si es el debe es mayor que el haber haga tal cosa, y el else lo contrario. Pongo un rubro, pongo el debe 500 y el haber 4000 y me toma el primer if, pero si pongo 600 y 8000 no, pasa al else.

```
    def add_product(self):
    try:
        if (rows:= self.listbox1.selection_get()):
            if rows in RESULTADOS:
                if self.price_debe.get() > self.price_haber.get():
                    negativo_a = (int(self.price_debe.get()) - int(self.price_haber.get()))
                    query = 'INSERT INTO balance (id, cuenta, debe, haber, activo, pasivo, negativo, positivo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
                    parameters = (self.nro_cuenta.get(), rows, self.price_debe.get(), self.price_haber.get(), 0, 0, negativo_a, 0)
                    self.run_query(query, parameters)
                    self.pasivo_negativo(self.nro_cuenta.get())
                    self.mesagge['text'] = 'Se guardo el resultado negativo'
                else:
                    positivo_a = (int(self.price_haber.get()) - int(self.price_debe.get()))
                    query = 'INSERT INTO balance (id, cuenta, debe, haber, activo, pasivo, negativo, positivo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
                    parameters = (self.nro_cuenta.get(), rows, self.price_debe.get(), self.price_haber.get(), 0, 0, 0, positivo_a)
                    self.run_query(query, parameters)
                    self.pasivo_negativo(self.nro_cuenta.get())
                    self.mesagge['text'] = 'Se guardo el resultado positivo'
            else:
                query = 'INSERT INTO balance (id, cuenta, debe, haber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'    
                parameters = (self.nro_cuenta.get(), rows, self.price_debe.get(), self.price_haber.get())
                self.run_query(query, parameters)
                self.price_debe.delete(0, END)
                self.price_debe.insert(0, int(0))
                self.price_haber.delete(0, END)
                self.price_haber.insert(0, int(0))
                self.nro_cuenta.delete(0, END)
                self.mesagge['text'] = 'Se guardo con exito'
        else:
            self.mesagge['text'] = 'Hay un error'
    except (sqlite3.IntegrityError, TclError):
        self.mesagge['text'] = 'No hay datos o ya esta cargado'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un ListBox almacena cadenas, por lo que comparas cadenas, no enteros. Esto significa que se ordenan y comparan en orden lexicográfico, es decir en función del orden de sus codepoints Unicode:

> ```
> >>> "500" > "4000"
> True
> >>> "600" > "8000"
> False
> ```

Al comparar por orden lexicográfico primero se mira el primer carácter de ambos, en el primer caso es "5" y "4", como "5" es mayor que "4" se retorna inmediatamente True. En el segundo caso como "6" es menor que "8" se retorna "False". Si ambos caracteres fueran iguales, se compara de forma idéntica el segundo, etc.

Esto nos lleva a que "2" es mayor que "100000000000000000000000000000". La solución es simplemente hacer un casting a entero o `float` (dependiendo si tienes o no decimales) previamente:

> ```
> >>> int("500") > int("4000")
> False
>
> >>> int("600") > int("8000")
> False
> ```

En tu caso sería:

```
if int(self.price_debe.get()) > int(self.price_haber.get()):
```

o si vas a trabajar con floats:

```
if float(self.price_debe.get()) > float(self.price_haber.get()):
```